# Does Double Median Absolute Deviation work for every distribution for the purpose of outlier detection?

Tags: statistics, outlier, distribution

I am using Double Median Absolute Deviation for finding outliers in a 1-D data. As mean with standard deviation gets influenced easily by outliers, that's why I chose median based approach. And the reason for choosing Double MAD over MAD was that MAD doesn't give appreciable results when gets a asymmetric distribution. I also want that the algorithm should be pessimistic in classifying points as outliers i.e. the algorithm must set tighter limits.

So I have 2 questions basically-

1. Is MAD (or Double MAD) good for this purpose of outlier detection? Or is any better approach(it can be statistical or any clustering/density/distance based algorithm as well)?
2. There must be some distributions(or corner cases) for which MAD (or Double MAD) will fail. If possible, I want to know such cases.

Comment: for example [multi-modal underlying distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution) can fail the MAD approach, without providing a detailed answer I think MAD (and similar mean-based approaches) will work only for uni-modal distributions. Else they should be fine

Comment: see also https://www.jstor.org/stable/2291267?seq=1

Comment: edit: work best on uni-modal and symmetric distributions